# Blade templating with angular2 templating?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have problem because im using angular with laravel.I added this in routes.php

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');        // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');   // for escaped data
```

But its not working because im getting an error when i display data from angular.
Any  suggestion how can i fix this?

For example if i say:

`{{'test'}}` it works but if i say `{{response.test}}` where response is from angular i get an error because laravel thinks that is his.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Comment: i tried this Blade:setContentTags from tutorial but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Blade will ignore anything preceded by the `@` character. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

first confing laravel blade and angular js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []) 
  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%=');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });
</script>
```

write your angular code like this

```
<%= cs.Category_name %>
```

Comment: is this for anuglar 2 ?

Comment: im gettin errro because of angular.module that is not recognized

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at (index):112